# Renomear Workspace no VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

Estou a um tempo tentando renomear meu workspace no VSCode mas não encontrei nenhuma opção ou comando que o faça, alguém sabe como renomear ou como criar algum novo com um nome que eu queira?

[image: Imagem exibindo as configurações do Workspace]

Comment: Vá em arquivo e selecione a opção salvar workspace como, e colocar o nome que você quer

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda!